# FileMaker Pro 12 - Using Commas As Separators For Address Export

Tags: filemaker

FMP12

I need to use commas to separate data from customer addresses. The address is imported into a notes field like this: "1234 East Palm Ave, Berkeley, Ca 94150".

My script needs to recognize if the street name is 2 or 3 words, and if the city name is 1 or 2 words. The info gets broken up into a couple different Set Variables $streetName, $CityName, $ZipCode, and exported to create a new customer profile.

I was trying to do that with a string search function that finds the position of the first and second instand of each "," but my function isn't working. Any hints about which function to use would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the formatting is consistent, try:

**$streetName** =

```
Let (
tokens = Substitute ( Address ; ", " ; ¶ )
;
GetValue ( tokens ; 1 )
)
```

**$cityName** =

```
Let (
tokens = Substitute ( Address ; ", " ; ¶ )
;
GetValue ( tokens ; 2 )
)
```

**$zipCode** =

```
RightWords ( Address ; 1 )
```